How to write dynamic native SQL Query in spring data JPA @Query?
extFieldSql is Dynamic SQL like:(JSON_EXTRACT(user_information_json, '$.cerNum') LIKE '%001%')
    @Query(
            value = "select distinct u.* from user where ?1 ",
            countQuery = "select count(distinct u.user_id) where  ?1 ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<User> findUserPage(String extFieldSql, Pageable pageable);


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
